# Dynamic display of comments and answers on the site

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Wouldn't it be nice if AJAX be used to dynamically display the comments on and the answers to ones question?

Comment: How would this make it nicer? You mean you wouldn't have to reload?

Comment: There are tons of things that would be nice. If you strongly feel that something is needed, please elaborate on your idea and present some arguments.

Comment: Yes I mean exactly that you wouldn't have to reload to view the new comments and answers coming up. Refreshing the page at intervals to view updates coming is history. The AJAX technique is already being used by comments, messages on Facebook and Google+ alike. GMail and the new Yahoo! Mail also incorporate in situ page refresh to new incoming mail. I still remember the days when one had to keep refreshing on his/her inbox when mail was expected. It is a pretty standard feature request, I'd say!

Answer (score 1):

This has already been asked for and declined on Meta Stack Overflow: [Ajax refreshing for questions and answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23486/ajax-refreshing-for-questions-and-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Something quite close to this was [implemented recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox).

> We have deployed a new feature that hopefully help with keeping you
>   instantly updated as new questions and answers are posted.  All sites
>   except for Stack Overflow have a new activity indicator on the
>   homepage which will show when new posts are asked or answered.

[image: new activity]
[image]

Comment: If you are viewing a question, there is also a banner for new edits. I think a button also pops up to view new comments as well.

Comment: @iglvzx yeah, I couldn't find an image for that